# Android Widget : gesture not working

Tags: android

am trying to add double tap gesture to a widget in Android. I tried [the usual way](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html) to add gesture to activity. It's not working. I see [here in another Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167517/are-android-app-widgets-for-home-screen-allowed-gestures) that one needs to use RemoteViews and Listview or such a component in order to add gestures to widgets. But this answer is in 2011. Is there an easier way? I haven't used these components in my widget, but now this new gesture requirement came up. This'll need me to rewrite a lot of the code.
Here's what I tried:

```
public class AppWidgetProvider_Basic
        extends AppWidgetProvider
        implements
            GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,
            GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener{
...
private GestureDetectorCompat mDetector;
...
@Override 
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    ...
    this.initializeGestureListener();
}
...
...
private void initializeGestureListener() {
    Log.d(MEConstants.APP_NAME, "initializeGestureListener");
    mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this.currentContext, this);
    mDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);
}



@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d(Constants.APP_NAME, "onDown");
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                       float velocityY) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent arg0, MotionEvent arg1, float arg2,
                        float arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent arg0) {
    Log.d(Constants.APP_NAME, "single tap");
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
...
```

}

Comment: Add the code that wasnt working. GestureDetector is the way to go.

Comment: @EE66 , added the code in my question above

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Detecting_Common_Gestures_using_the_Android_Gesture_Detector_Class)
. One of the diffrences is that the dev returned true for *onDown*. Its either there or where u attach the gesture detector to the view.